# Make page invalid in server code

Tags: validation, server

I am creating forms from code that include checkboxes and there is no validator that can make sure a checkbox is checked on its own like existence and compare validators can. Checkboxes need use custom validators which will not work for me because the checkbox id is arbitrary and there can be any number of them with any number requiring the check. I  can get a custom validator to call a server function but it does not know and cannot reference the field checkbox data since everything is done on the fly.  The HTML page is just a div that I add the code generated form too.

I manage the data in my form by reading the posted form data. To complicate everything,  an unchecked checkbox does not put a value in the form data so I must check for its non-existence to know it is not checked. I have all this working fine except for the validation status.  I know which checkboxes are not valid and I have added my own validation message to the form and the validation summary is updated. Basically everything is written and working.

The problem - I really want to set Page.IsValid to false and make the page officially not valid having my own custom code validation be a properly behaving validator on the page.  Should I just screw it and return with my validation marking up the page?

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 0):

I found something on the web that helped.

Make a class with for your own validator.

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace YourNameSpace
{

    public class ValidatorError : IValidator
    {
        private ValidatorError(string message)
        {
            ErrorMessage = message;
            IsValid = false;
        }
 
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public bool IsValid { get; set; }
        public string ValidationGroup { get; set; }
   
 
        public static void Display(Page currentPage, string message)
        {
            currentPage.Validators.Add(new ValidatorError(message));
        }
    }
}
```

The in the Page_Load before the validate call.

```html
bool localValidationError = false;
public List<string> validateErrorList = null;

//  localValidationError and the validateErrorList are set in some parsing code in Page_Init()

if (localValidationError && validateErrorList != null) {
   foreach (string message in validateErrorList) {
             ValidatorError.Display(Page, message);
     }
}
Page.Validate();
```

My validators were in a validator group which would not work, I had to remove the group.  All of the this gets Page,Valid to be set and the page ValidationSummary to be populated most of the time. The ValidatorError errors don't come up when the list is longer but they do show when it is shorter.  It works good enough I suppose.

George